# JAVA UI Element for selecting either one or both

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I need to create a dialog with two options. [x]Option 1 and [] Option 2. Option 1 is chosen by default. But user can unselect Option1, then choose Option2. He can select both O1 and O2. So the scenario is choose either one of them or both. A checkbox doesn't seem to be very intuitive. Is there any other tip?

Thanks...

Comment: checkbox can be good option provided you write some code in its handler event.

Comment: ^Yes. I can validate. But I just wanted to know if there is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the choice is between check boxes and radio buttons.  Since you need to allow multiple selection, a radio button is not appropriate.  The only case you need to prevent is when nothing is selected.  You can use check boxes and only enable the next operation when at least one option is checked.  If this is a dialog, then the "Okay" or "Next" button can be disabled until that condition is met by listening for actions on the check boxes.

There is no other standard control that would cover the behaviour you are looking for without additional case handling.

Answer (score 0):

If the possible combinations are limited as in your case (i.e. only two options which results in three possibilities), one of the following alternatives may also be considered:

- Using a [drop-down menu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop-down_list) with the three combinations.
- Using three buttons.

But as always: It depends on the use case…